# SQL Statement with 3 References and Date Statement

Tags: sql-server, join, sharepoint, sql-server-2014

i am actually messing around with MS SQL 2014 and trying to create a statement for our Sharepoint Server.

We have a Timecard Apllication where we see which one of our Workers is working and who isnt.

I have 3 Tables
`[easyjob].[dbo].[Address]` where i have `IDAddress` as Join Column.
This Table Containts Name of the Worker.

`[easyjob].[dbo].[TimeCardUser]` where i have `IDAdress and IDTimeCardUser`
This Table Contains the User for the Timecard Application.

`[easyjob].[dbo].[TimeCardWorkTime]` where i have `IDTImeCardUser`
This Table Contains the working time. For that i have already a working SQL Statement that gives me the Workers that are in House:

```
`SELECT [IdTimeCardWorkTime]
      ,[IdTimeCardUser]
      ,[IdTimeCardWorkTimeType]
      ,[WorkStart]
      ,[WorkEnd]
      ,[Duration]
      ,[IdUserCreated]
      ,[IdUserUpdated]
      ,[CreationTime]
      ,[UpdateTime]
      ,[Description]
  FROM [easyjob].[dbo].[TimeCardWorkTime] WHERE [WorkEnd] is NULL AND [WorkStart] BETWEEN 
   CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))`
```

Which gives

`IdTimeCardWorkTime IdTimeCardUser  IdTimeCardWorkTimeType  WorkStart   WorkEnd Duration    IdUserCreated   IdUserUpdated   CreationTime    UpdateTime  Description
3655    22  1   2015-12-03 07:55:00.000 NULL    NULL    55  55  2015-12-03 07:55:00.000 2015-12-03 07:56:00.033 NULL`

Now i just have to get the Names to the Output.

Then this will be shown at our sharepoint intranet.

Can somebody help me.
I will appreciate it.

Regards

Sascha

Comment: what is your expected output? do u want to include the name in the select statement given?

Comment: Hi there. Actually is just want the name of the worker in house. And this is the list i have with my statement but i need the names.

Comment: Then you must a key have a key column to join [easyjob].[dbo].[TimeCardWorkTime] table with  [easyjob].[dbo].[Address]  table for getting the name

Comment: Thats what i try. But i failed because of the way through the third table.

Comment: you mean you dont have any key column in the table?

Comment: As i described. I have a Key which keys with TimeCardUser Table and that contains the IDAdress key that is used in the Adress table which contains the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have Try Something Like Below

```
 SELECT T.[IdTimeCardWorkTime]
      , T.[IdTimeCardUser]
      , A.[NAME]
      , T.[IdTimeCardWorkTimeType]
      , T.[WorkStart]
      , T.[WorkEnd]
      , T.[Duration]
      , T.[IdUserCreated]
      , T.[IdUserUpdated]
      , T.[CreationTime]
      , T.[UpdateTime]
      , T.[Description]
  FROM [easyjob].[dbo].[TimeCardWorkTime] T
  INNER JOIN [easyjob].[dbo].[TimeCardUser] W
    ON (T. IDTimeCardUser  = W.IDTImeCardUser)
  INNER JOIN [easyjob].[dbo].[Address] A
    ON (W. IDAdress  = A.IDAdress)
  WHERE T.[WorkEnd] IS NULL 
    AND T.[WorkStart] BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Hope This Helps

Comment: Thats it.Thanks a lot